# When starting a new public ethereum blockchain can I disclose the genesis file?

Tags: genesis

I am using the ethereum codebase to create a new ethereum based blockchain.  I don't want to call it a private blockchain because it will be public.

I have been able to set it up, created my own blockchain and all is good.

I am not sure if one can disclose the genesis file or publish it for example to github.

I cannot seem to find any information as to the sensitivity of this file and I cannot find where the public ethereum Genesis file is located to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main net and Ropsten and Rinkeby test nets all have their own genesis files and are hard-coded into the Geth client for convenience. You can get more info here [genesis.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/genesis.go)

Comment: Thanks, it seems it would be wise to also take this approach and embed my genesis file data into this format also.